# Can I save presets for the inset tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am currently working on a model where I find myself making 4 different repeated insets with different depths and thicknesses for bolt head recesses.
The inset tool remembers the previous used setting. Is there a way to load and save a preset for it, and save me typing it in each time and reduce the number of post it notes stuck to my monitor?

If the answer is no could someone indicate if this is the sort of automation script suitable for a relative newcomer to scripting? I'm tempted but a little wary to give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way save for scripting to load and save presets for operators that do not explicitly support it in the toolbar. This would not be my recommendation for a *first* project in blender API however after a few basic tutorials (maybe [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ALfl4tebiQM) ) you should be able to do this sort of thing on your own.

Edit: Another alternative that comes to my mind is [duplication](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication). I can't tell if that is helpful but certainly making one bolt by hand is far easier than making a script to do it.